# Java prints "null" while taking in array of strings as input from the user using Scanner and ends abruptly

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ArrayofArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] ListofNames = {
            {"barbie","cinderella","troomtroom"},
            {"wonderwoman","captainmarvel","Cheetah"}
        };
        for(String[] i : ListofNames) {
            for(String x: i) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
        int r,c;
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter rows\n");
        r = obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter columns\n");
        c = obj.nextInt();
        String[][] Inputnames = new String[r][c];
        for(int j = 0;j<r;j++) {
            for(int l = 0;l<c;l++) {
                System.out.println("Enter name\n");
                Inputnames[j][l] = obj.nextLine();
            }
        for(int m = 0;m<r;m++) {
            for(int n = 0;n<c;n++) {
                System.out.println(Inputnames[m][n]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was learning java and when I tried to to take in Array of Arrays consisting of strings as user input, it printed out null and didnt take further inputs. What am I missing out?

The output is like this on the cmd:

C:\Users\dynam\Desktop\Java Files>java ArrayofArrays
barbie
cinderella
troomtroom
wonderwoman
captainmarvel
Cheetah
Enter rows

2
Enter columns

1
Enter name

null
Enter name

batman

batman

Comment: What was the full output of the program, include it in the question.

Comment: okay added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Scanner.nextInt method does not read the newline character in your input created after pressing "Enter," and so the call to Scanner.nextLine returns after reading that new line.

Also Looks like your for loops are messed up, try the following code (cleaned up a bit)-

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Scanner;

class ArrayofArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] ListofNames = {
                {"barbie", "cinderella", "troomtroom"},
                {"wonderwoman", "captainmarvel", "Cheetah"}
        };
        for (String[] i : ListofNames) {
            for (String x : i) {
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
        int r, c;
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter rows\n");
        r = obj.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter columns\n");
        c = obj.nextInt();
        obj.nextLine();
        String[][] Inputnames = new String[r][c];
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < c; l++) {
                System.out.println("Enter name\n");
                Inputnames[j][l] = obj.nextLine();

            }
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < r; m++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < c; n++) {
                System.out.println(Inputnames[m][n]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a ton,like you said,I had a mistake in the braces of my for loop.Now works.

Comment: Additionally, you should close your scanner at the end to prevent resource leaks.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen a lot in several questions. The issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) more in detail.

To fix your issue, replace the `obj.nextInt()` with `Integer.parseInt(obj.nextLine())`. So basically your code should look like the following:

```
System.out.println("Enter rows\n");
r = Integer.parseInt(obj.nextLine());
System.out.println("Enter columns\n");
c = Integer.parseInt(obj.nextLine());
```

If by any chance your will enter something else than an integer here, you might have to use a `try-catch` block to make sure you deal with `NumberFormatException`s.

Comment: Thanks,this solved it.I cannot upvote as I dont have enough "reputation".